# Ceiling Light with Ballast in Private Elevator Foyer

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

Trying to figure out the wiring for a ceiling fixture in a private elevator lobby. Not sure if that makes a difference since there's no window in the room. Just wondering if the light is required to always be on 24/7 or something quirky like that.
There's only one switch box in the room, and the wires are capped off. One of the black wires is hot.

[image: Wall wiring]

What makes me wonder if there is a different requirement for the foyer is the light fixture in the ceiling is unlike anything else in the condo. Wires appear to go from the wall to this ballast in the ceiling, and then to the red/yellow/blue wires in the fixture.

[image: Ceiling Ballast]
[image: Ceiling Fixture]
[image: Bulb Sockets]

Wondering if I can just remove the ballast and fixture and replace it with a flush mount LED light, and then not sure if I should put in a switch or not.
Also,  I don't see any current in the light sockets, so it could mean the ballast is bad, or the wireing is not what I expect I suppose.

Comment: If you're in the US, the public areas of a condo are usually off-limits to DIYers so we don't burn down someone else's living quarters. Your best _legal_ recourse is to put it all back and have the condo association have a licensed electrician come out and replace the light. And, since it's a windowless room, there might be a requirement to have the light on 24/7, though I don't know if that's code or condo rules.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. Thank you!